# Set the admin permission using acl

Tags: magento2

1.I have to set the admin permisssion using ACL
   2. If the acl value is checked for the create acl value
3. Then it display the Product information else leave them blank

I have to set the admin permssion . I they don't have the permission then it display the the text in the Product Description. If they have the Permsission then it displays the Product name

How it would manage , I am using acl permission but everytime it shows the true value

Comment: Can you please explain more and and add tag of the specific version of Magento

Comment: okay I will explain here

Comment: I have to set the admin permssion . I they don't have the permission then it display the the text in the Product Description. If they have the Permsission then it displays the Product name

Comment: How it would manage , I am using acl permission but everytime it shows the true value